# checking two different 2D arrays to find a match c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am currently writing a memory game and I am stuck a little bit on checking my Arrays. how the program works:

When someone makes a guess it checks the tiles and saves the tiles in a 2D Array for the bot, which allows the bot to memorize where things are on the board.

I am trying to write a 2D array for loop that checks for a match between the 2D array containing the answers and the 2D array for the bot.

When a match is found I want to save the values, however my program is not working that way at the moment,

I would just like some insight on what I am doing wrong with my for loops.
I have looked around and read through some of my C++ Text Books and couldn't find anything.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuKhw.png)

```
 //2d Arrays
//bot array changes each time someone guesses

string botArray[6][6] = {
    { "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-" },
    { "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-" },
    { "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-" },
    { "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-" },
    { "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-" },
    { "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-" }
};
string pairs[6][6] = { 
{ "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c" },
{ "d", "d", "e", "e", "f", "f" },
{ "g", "g", "h", "h", "i", "i" },
{ "j", "j", "k", "k", "l", "l" },
{ "m", "m", "n", "n", "o", "o" },
{ "p", "p", "q", "q", "r", "r" }
 };

                  for (int r1 = 0; r1 < 6; r1++) {
                    for (int c1 = 0; c1 < 6; c1++) {
                        for (int r2 = 0; r2 < 6; r2++) {
                            for (int c2 = 0; c2 < 6; c2++) {
                                if (botArray[r1][c1] == pairs[r1][c1]){
                                   if(botArray[r2][c2] == pairs[r2][c2]) {
                                     if (r1 != r2 && c1 != c2) {
                                    row1 = r1;
                                    col1 = c1;
                                    row2 = r2;
                                    col2 = c2;
                                }
                               }
                                else{
                                    row1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
                                    row2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
                                    col1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
                                    col2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
             }
//values are printed outside of the for loop after
//they are assigned in the if statement
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is the current output? And it sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @FirstStep in the output photo you can see that there are matches that are stored in the  bot's 2D array but the bot doesn't even recognise there is a match

Comment: Questions on stackoverflow.com must include complete information in the question itself. Links to external sites can stop working at any time, rendering the archived question meaningless, and are not acceptable.

Comment: As the users take time to read, understand and respond to questions, please take time and write a complete question with inputs, outputs and what you tried. As a form of respect.

Comment: Your random assignment should not be in the loop (and you don't check that random values are *free*).

Comment: @Jarod42 if I attempt to assign outside the loop my loop values are uninitialized

Comment: Instead of `botArray`, I would use a `using position = std::pair<int, int>; std::vector<std::pair<position, std::string>> botKnowledge;` and remove pairs once formed.

Comment: I would also use 1D array. and just display it as 2D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your logic is wrong with (comment added)

```
// Loop
if (botArray[r1][c1] == pairs[r1][c1]) { // Bot knows that case
    if (botArray[r2][c2] == pairs[r2][c2]) { // Bot knows that case
        if (r1 != r2 && c1 != c2) { // Different case
            row1 = r1;
            col1 = c1;
            row2 = r2;
            col2 = c2;
        }
    } else { // Hit each time that we found a second unknown case
             // So overwrite previous found solution
        row1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        row2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        col1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        col2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    }
}
```

It should be something like

```
// Loop
if ((r1 != r2 || c1 != c2) // Different case
    && botArray[r1][c1] != "-" // Known card
    && botArray[r1][c1] == botArray[r2][c2]) // Pair found
    // Missing: Not already displayed
{
    row1 = r1;
    col1 = c1;
    row2 = r2;
    col2 = c2;
    return; // No need more processing
}

// and after loop, to handle when no pair found
do {
    row1 = rand() % 6 + 1; // Random play
    row2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    col1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    col2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
} while ((row1 != row2 || col1 != col2) // Different case
         // Potentially other condition, as at least one unknown case
     )
```

I would implement it something like:

```
class BotPlayer
{
public:
    explicit BotPlayer(std::size_t size) {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i) {
            data.emplace_back(i, "");
        }
    }

    std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> selectMove() {
        // Try to find 2 cards with same value
        std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){ return lhs.second < rhs.second; } );
        auto it = std::adjacent_find(data.begin(), data.end(), [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){ return lhs.second == rhs.second && !lhs.second.empty(); });

        if (it == data.end()) { // No known pairs -> play randomly (but choose unknown cards)
            auto isUnknown = [](const auto& e){ return e.second.empty(); };
            it = std::partition(data.begin(), data.end(), isUnknown);
            std::shuffle(data.begin(), it, rnd);
            it = data.begin();
        }
        return {it->first, std::next(it)->first};
    }

    void reveal(std::size_t pos, const std::string& value)
    {
        // Update our knowledge.
        std::cout << "> " << pos << " is " << value << std::endl;
        auto it = std::find_if(data.begin(), data.end(), [&](const auto& p) { return p.first == pos; });

        it->second = value;
    }

    void foundPair(std::size_t pos1, std::size_t pos2)
    {
        // So we don't have to worry about those cards anymore
        data.erase(std::find_if(data.begin(), data.end(), [&](const auto& p) { return p.first == pos1; }));
        data.erase(std::find_if(data.begin(), data.end(), [&](const auto& p) { return p.first == pos2; }));
    }

private:
    std::mt19937 rnd;

    // for each remaining position to play,
    // associate the associated value,
    // empty for unknown.
    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> data;
};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/HQ8nEn)